# WebRTC Video Streaming fails through Airtel Broadband, works fine with 4G Hotspot

Tags: webrtc

I am trying out the WebRTC examples of [MuazKhan](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pluginfree-Screen-Sharing). It is working perfectly fine when the broadcaster is on AWS/Azure(or any other network) and the receiver is through my phones 4G network. But as soon as I switch to my broadband from 4G, the video stream is unable to connect and I the video player keeps on trying. Therefore I assumed that the problem is of the router NATting and will be resolved if I use a tried-n-tested TURN service such as Xirsys.

Sadly, even after using their TURN servers, I still am blocked with my broadband connection issue as mentioned above. Here are a few queries that I wanted to discuss:-

1. This issue seems to be due to NATting through my broadbands routers. Shouldn't using the TURN server solve it?
2. How can I verify if even the TURN servers are getting used and its not just the STUN servers.
3. Can this issue be due to the Signalling Server?
4. Do i need to enable some specific protocols in my router to make this work?
5. What else could be responsible for the issue that I should debug?

Comment: I too face this issue. Any updates will be helpful.

Comment: :-) Finally someone who could share my pain. Couldn't make that working. I switched to Red5Pro paid service.